# Required certain params on certain actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a requirement to need to validate presence of some params in certain situations. Here is the example of that :

In my user controller, for update action, I am required to validate the presence of these params. Same deal for car controller, update action as well, you could see recurring theme here. Params are `additional_info`.

My base controller provides `additional_info_params` which pulls the right data from the request.

Here is what I tried so far. I created a AR controller concern and included it in the controller, here is some code:

```
module ClassMethods
  def require_additional_info_for(*methods)
    binding.pry
    return unless methods.include?(action_name)
    if additional_info_params.empty?
      head 400
    end
  end
end
```

My idea was to be able to define methods that require these params on the top of controller file, just like `before_action` from rails or `skip_authorization_check` from cancan. Like so:

```
MyController < BaseController
  include Concerns::AdditionalInformation
  require_additional_info_for :update

  def update
    ...
  end
end
```

This code above however does not work as I intended, mainly because this fires on the request class without much knowledge about the request (where I need to derive action name from via `action_name`).

So how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but i suggest you to use the `before_action` callback!

In a 'abstract' controller, register your method like this:

```
 class SameController < ApplicationController
   ...
   protected
     def require_additional_params
       render status: :unprocessable_entity if additional_info_params.empty?
     end
 end
```

After this, all the controllers who will use this methods, must extends `SameController`, and runs `before_action` passing the above method for the wanted actions, for example:

```
class UserController < SameController
  before_action :require_additional_params, only: [:action1, :action2]
end
```

**Note**: You can put the `require_additional_params` in a module and include in your controller, or just put it in the `ApplicationController`

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at making these regular strong params in the respective controller. It looks something like this:

```
def update_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:engine, :wheels, :rims).tap do |car_params|
    car_params.require(:engine)
  end
end
```

This would expect a top-level `:car` key params (which it strips), and require an `:engine` param, but allow the other 2 (`:wheels` and `:rims`). If `:engine` isn't present, it will raise a `ActionController::ParameterMissing` (just like if `:cars` was missing)

This is straight from the [action controller strong params docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) (last example at bottom)

I'll sometimes throw these into separate private methods on the respective controller, so there would also possibly be a `create_params` method with different requirements. I prefer this method over using a custom method as a before_action.